# Why is there a compile error when including OpenSSL static library?

Tags: ios4, openssl

I have some problems using OpenSSL.  I'm following the [tutorial for compiling OpenSSL for iOS](http://www.x2on.de/2010/07/13/tutorial-iphone-app-with-compiled-openssl-1-0-0a-library/), but it is still not working.  Here is my problem:

1. Change directories into `crypto/ui/ui_openssl.c`.
2. Build OpenSSL for i368 iPhone simulator.
3. Copy the `include`, `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` to the project folder.
4. Drag `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` to project tree.
5. Change the build info.

It worked with `openssl-1.0.0c`.  Then as I was coding `#include <openssl/md5.h>` and building, I got the error "no such file or directory."
[image]
Help!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ben do you something like this in your project 
[image]

Comment: of course  i did.the step 4 did that. the libssl.a &libcryto.a are compiled by myself

Comment: expand to see the no. of libraries

Comment: that's it ,the picture i have upload,it doesn't look like different at all.Thank you robin!it's very kind of you~

Comment: i have solved it ,i've made a mistake whit the header search path ,that it

Comment: @ben I have put the include folder in header search path ("${SRCROOT}/include"). I still get the same error. How did you fix it?

Comment: @PsychoDad which image are you talking about?

Comment: @Robin the image in the answer

Comment: @PsychoDad, you know just used cmd+shift+3 key to take a snapshot and then clicked on the image icon while answering this question.