# Link error attempting to build app with Cocoapods using xcodebuild on Jenkins

Tags: xcode, jenkins, cocoapods

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins CI instance for our app development project. I have jobs working that run logic and application tests using the *Debug* configuration but I'm struggling to build the IPA as I get a linkage error during compilation.

```
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The app uses Cocoapods and I'm building with the Jenkins XCode plugin.

I searched for similar problems and tried/verified a bunch of things:

- I am using a workspace.
- I'm running `pod install` before the xcodebuild step.
- I've checked that architectures on the project itself, the target and Pods are the same – *standard (armv7, armv7s)* – as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8824757/565049)
- I tried various solutions from [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/270)
- I tried various settings for *Derived Data* locations as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16803411/565049) and similar ones
- The Podfile specifies `platform :ios, :deployment_target => "6.0"`

At that point I'm at a loss for what more to try.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling the workspace and not the project? If you aren't already, try using the Jenkins Xcode Plugin and specify the 'Xcode Workspace File'.  The Xcode plugin may help clear up any other possible misdirections as well.  I had the same issue last week, spent hours upon hours only to realize I had Jenkins compiling the Xcode project, not the Xcode workspace.  Also, go to the actual directly of the project Jenkins is compiling, open it in Xcode and see if you can compile it yourself - it will also be easier for you to debug it through Xcode.

Comment: Yes, definitely using the workspace & not the project. As I say, I have a very similar configuration working for running logic & application tests just fine.

Comment: I see, I know, its annoying ... in case you didn't try this too, maybe this page (#4 in the FAQ) may help - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Creating-a-project-that-uses-CocoaPods

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using to build? There is some weirdness with Xcode5 and Jenkins.

Comment: I have the same problem here since upgrading to Xcode5. Works fine from Xcode but fails with `xcodebuild`.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Build Output Directory' setting can also cause this.

Changing the value of the 'Build Output Directory' from a relative path to a fully specified path fixed it for me.

E.g. instead of 'MyOutputDirectory' use '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/home/jobs/JenkinsProject/workspace/MyOutputDirectory'

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be because you have different (custom) build configurations.

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/121

Try adding following search path to "Library Search Paths" (For all configs)

```
$(SYMROOT)/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try choose your Pods project and set Build Settings->Build Active Architectures Only->NO for Release and Debug, repeat this action for each target in Pods.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the XCode plugin, so my answer may be considered somewhat unresponsive, but here is how I got it working.

I added a build step that looks like this:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
echo $WORKSPACE
cd "/Users/[jenkins-accountname]/.jenkins/jobs/[jobname]/workspace/[xcode project name]"
pod install
xcrun xcodebuild -workspace [your workspace (not project) name] -scheme [the build scheme to build] clean build -destination "platform=iOS,name=CurtsiPhone" -destination-timeout 120
```

The **-destination** and **-destination-timeout** were key build arguments for success. My project will only build on the phone since it uses specialized libraries, so my phone has to be plugged in so the XCode can find it.  You may not need this if your project will build in the simulator, however I only got it working when I explicitly specified a destination.

If the XCode plugin allows you to state extra compile arguments, you should try these.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using XCode 5 then I think [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/1352) should help

basically update your Gemfile (or create one if it doesn't exist) and add:

```
gem 'cocoapods', :git => 'http://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods', :branch => 'xcode-5-support'
gem 'xcodeproj', :git => 'http://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj', :branch => 'redacted-support'
```

Also if you have things like `config.build_settings['ARCHS'] = 'armv7'` in your Podfile, don't forget to get rid of it, you'll need to have armv7s too.

Hope this helps, cause it saved me a few days of nightmare.