# Linker command exic code 1

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have got error from linker.

I spent a lot of time with this issue.

```
Ld /Users/n/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Love-firlokvkfitdaefazzayuqyntwxm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Love.app/Love normal i386
    cd "/Love"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk -L/Users/n/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Love_-firlokvkfitdaefazzayuqyntwxm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/n/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Love-firlokvkfitdaefazzayuqyntwxm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Love/Pods/Crashlytics -F/Love/Pods/Fabric -filelist /Users/n/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Love-firlokvkfitdaefazzayuqyntwxm/Build/Intermediates/Love.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Love.build/Objects-normal/i386/Love.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -Wl,-U,_JSContextGetGlobalObject -Wl,-U,_JSEvaluateScript -Wl,-U,_JSGlobalContextCreate -Wl,-U,_JSGlobalContextRelease -Wl,-U,_JSObjectCallAsFunction -Wl,-U,_JSObjectIsFunction -Wl,-U,_JSObjectMake -Wl,-U,_JSObjectSetProperty -Wl,-U,_JSStringCopyCFString -Wl,-U,_JSStringCreateWithCFString -Wl,-U,_JSStringRelease -Wl,-U,_JSValueIsObject -Wl,-U,_JSValueIsString -Wl,-U,_JSValueMakeString -Wl,-U,_JSValueToStringCopy -lc++ -lz -framework AFNetworking -framework AMViralSwitch -framework BFPaperTableViewCell -framework CRGradientNavigationBar -framework CarbonKit -framework Crashlytics -framework DACircularProgress -framework FCUUID -framework FMDB -framework Fabric -framework INTULocationManager -framework IQKeyboardManager -framework JGProgressHUD -framework KILabel -framework MKMapView_ZoomLevel -framework MMMaterialDesignSpinner -framework MMobileApi -framework Mantle -framework Masonry -framework MaterialKit -framework Overcoat -framework RESideMenu -framework SDWebImage -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework TTTAttributedLabel -framework UIAlertView_Blocks -framework UICKeyChainStore -framework UIColor_BFPaperColors -framework UIKit -framework XCDYouTubeKit -framework objc_geohash -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lPods-Love\ Istanbul -weak_framework Pods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/n/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Love-firlokvkfitdaefazzayuqyntwxm/Build/Intermediates/Love\ Istanbul.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Love.build/Objects-normal/i386/Love\ Istanbul_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/n/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Love_Istanbul-firlokvkfitdaefazzayuqyntwxm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Love.app/Love

ld: library not found for -lPods-Love
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can you help me with any suggestion?

Comment: show http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896717/3378413

Answer (score -1):

I had a faced a similar issue. Cleaning the build folder cleared the issue.

You could also try setting the "linker search paths" of the project (for both Debug and Release builds). If this library was in, say, a sibling directory to the project then you can set it like this:

$(PROJECT_DIR)/../Love/lib

(you want to avoid using an absolute path, instead keep the library directory relative to the project).

Comment: How do you clean it? What means did you use? You could improve your answer by adding helpful information to it.

Comment: @dakab As of Xcode 7, press Command+Option+Shift+K.

Or from the menu -> Product, press Option on your keyboard and you'll see Clean Build Folder.