# Xcode compiling Error ld: library not found for -lMPCategoryHelpers

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7

Tried all the possible solutions. Removed everything from App Target > Build Settings > Library Search Path , Upgraded Facebook SDK .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you using pods in your project

Comment: check  with this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896717/5362916

Comment: @Uma Yeah, The link which you directed . The solution might be correct. But i actually don't know which lib is missing.

Comment: pods are there in your project. open with workspace

Comment: @Uma Obviously i am using workspace.